# Vue Unable to push to another page from component

Tags: vue.js, routes

I am trying to push from one component to another using vue routes but am having issues!

This is my router->index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/pages/HelloWorld'
import GroupStart from '@/pages/GroupStart'
import NotFound from '@/pages/NotFound'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            name: 'HelloWorld',
            component: HelloWorld
        },
        {
            path: '/groupstart',
            name: 'GroupStart',
            component: GroupStart
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            name: 'Notfound',
            component: NotFound
        }
    ],
    mode: 'history'
})
```

Now, from my helloworld component I am trying to do this:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'This is the startpage'
    }
  }
}

this.$router.push({ path: '/groupstart' })
</script>
```

When doing so I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at eval (HelloWorld.vue?18db:17)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong and hoping for help :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write this `this.$router.push({ path: '/groupstart' })` inside some hook or method. if you want to do it right away when page is loaded, you can do something like this

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'This is the startpage'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
   this.$router.push({ path: '/groupstart' })
  }
}

</script>
```